# Comparing predictions from models

Tags: distributions, prediction, binary-data

I'm wondering how to compare the predictions of three different models - a logit, a probit and a linear probability model - when predicting a binary outcome. I'm currently working with simulated data, so I have access to both the latent variable $y$ and the binary outcome $Y$ with $\Pr(Y=1)=y$

I'm under the impression that normal tools for model selection (i.e. AIC) do no perform very well in this setting due to the difference in the assumptions of the models.

AUC or $corr(y,\hat{y})$ is a possibility, but I am wondering if this accurately reflects that the difference between models should be most evident in the *tails* of the distribution.

I hope the above makes my bewilderment clear, otherwise please feel free to ask for clarifications in the comments.

**EDITED FOR CLARIFICATION:** I am performing some simulations because I'm curious about the performance of various predictors. One often hears, for example, that the difference between the logit and probit model is in the thickness of the tails. I was merely wondering what would be the best statistic for comparing the fit of the predictions $y$ to the real values $\hat{y}$. Since I am comparing two nonlinear models with a linear model, the various forms of $R^2$ is ill-suited. Hope that helps!

Best,
Andreas

Comment: Yep, for example, you could clarify, upon reading this post from David Giles http://davegiles.blogspot.com.au/2012/06/yet-another-reason-for-avoiding-linear.html, why do you want to consider the third model: a linear probability model?

Comment: @Hibernating: That's not really what I'm interested in, but thanks for the link - I've also read some of Giles' other posts on the probit/LPM issue. He focuses primarily on marginal effects, while I'd prefer to focus on tail behaviour. I'm mostly looking for a metric to compare the predictions. 
(Why the LPM? I see it sometimes in empirical work, I'd like to get a grip of how wrong it really is).

Comment: No reason not to use AIC for model selection in this case if you use it in others. If the predictors are the same it just reflects the likelihood ratio between models. You'll need very large sample sizes to see much difference between logit & probit links - but that goes for any method of comparison.

Comment: @Scortchi, edited for clarity.

Comment: What version of $R^2$ to use depends on the form of the response (here dichotomous), not on the kind of model used to predict it. @charles' suggestions are sensible.

Comment: @Scortchi, $R^2$ isn't comparable between a model that is linear in the parameters and a model that's nonlinear - thus the multitude of pseudo-$R^2$ measures for the logit model.

Comment: For least squares fits $R^2$ doesn't bear the same interpretation for non-linear models as for linear models, & you're right to note that. But it's just a function of the residual & total sums of squares, so can be used for comparing least-squares fits to the same data - arguably it would be more straightforward to compare RSS directly.

Comment: The motivation of the multitude of pseudo-$R^2$s is to provide something analogous when least-squares isn't appropriate. As I don't know about all of them I'll retract what I said, & re-assert it just for the Cox-Snell pseudo $R^2$ - it depends just on the null likelihood (the same whatever the link function) & the model likelihoods (comparable as long as the response is measured the same way). [I prefer Brier scores or AUCs as measures of performance.]

Answer (score 1):

Still don't have a good grasp of what you're looking for. But if you're comparing binary classification models I wouldn't recommend just using AUC (a measure of discrimination)

Usually one uses three metrics together, choosing one from each of the three categories below. :
(1) Global measure:  scaled Brier or N's R-sq. The difference between Brier and N's R-sq may be significant due to different penalty functions
The Brier score is often preferred, but should usually be converted to a scale Brier score (thought this is less of an issue of all analysis on same dataset).
(2) Discrimination: AUC, discrimination slope
(3) Calibration:  calibration slope with calibration or validation graph

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've attempted to clarify above.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use probit or logit regression, because LPM could estimate numbers that are not probability.

Firstly look at your scatter plot, because in that graph you could see which model fits the data better. 
Then, if you need an estimate, you could try to use a Pseudo-R2. There are a wide variety of pseudo-R-square statistics as you can see here: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/faq/general/Psuedo_RSquareds.htm.

Comment: I'm perfectly aware of the problems with the LPM, I'm looking for a good statistic to quantify the quality of predictions. Since I am considering maybe 10,000 simulations, evaluating fit from a scatterplot will be rather difficult.